The image measure of Lebesgue measure
Recently, I have been contemplating the proof of this theorem. I would like to attempt a proof using techniques similar to those involving distribution functions. I wonder if there is a complete version of the proof for this theorem available?
Let $(E,\mathcal{E})$ be a standard measurable space. Let $\mu$ be a $\Sigma$-finite measure on $(E,\mathcal{E})$ and put $b=\mu(E)$, possibly $+\infty$. Then, there exists a mapping $h$ from $[0,b)$ into $E$, measurable relative to $\mathcal{B}([0,b))$ and $\mathcal{E}$, such that
$$
\mu=\lambda\circ h^{-1},
$$
where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure on $[0,b)$.
enter image description here

A measurable space $(E,\mathcal{E})$ is said to be \textbf{standard} if it is \textit{isomorphic} to $(F,\mathcal{B}(F))$ for some \textit{Borel subset} $F$ of $\mathbb{R}$.

If I understand you correctly, this is theorem 17.41 in section 17.F of Kechris's Classical Descriptive Set Theory. A complete proof is included there. If you want me to leave this as an answer instead of a comment, I'm happy to do so
